# Authorization in VueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, oauth-2.0

I want to create an authorization via Github OAuth2, after succcessfull authorization I want to get access_token and send him to nodejs app when he be save in database to current user, so:

my button in vuejs to launch authorization page in Github:

```
<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=SOME_CLIENT_ID&scope=repo/">
    <b-button variant="danger" style="height:38px;" class="ml-1">
        Connect
    </b-button>
</a>
```

and what now?

I need to create an endpoint in vuejs app to listen on callback and then on `post` get from response my `access_token` or I need to create an endpoint in my nodejs app to listen on callback, get on `post` response my `access_token` etc.?

I want to create this same function like in the `heroku` app, so after connected to github account I have a permission i see all private repo of authenticated user, have anybody any working example of vuejs and nodejs app?

thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you should send request via JS. Then just get response and use it

Comment: But how to get response on callback? I need to create an endpoint in vuejs app to get this access token?

Comment: You can create an endpoint on backend side, nodejs app or etc.

Comment: Have you an simple example of authentication with OAuth on frontend and backend?

Comment: So, I should, 1: click on button to auth via github oauth2 -> 2: get from response on callback my `code` and then send him to `node server` -> 3: on server run `post` request to get `access_token` from github api -> 4: get `access token` and save in db to current user -> 5: send info to vuejs

Comment: @Asimple that is ok?

Comment: No, you just passing response url, github will send post request there with all data.
All you need is just create endpoint and pass it's URL accordingly with other data(client_id, etc).

Comment: @Asimple can you show an example?

Comment: why do you want to store the access token in the db? that's not really a good idea ... it will expire soon anyway ... in vuejs use axios to call the github (as a callback it will return the token) and then send it along with your request to the server (nodejs)... on the server side you have to validate the token if it's not expired and valid .. this validation (authorization) has to happen on all endpoints you need to protect ... plus there will be some data about the user (like name, roles, ... ) which you need to use during the authorization too